# Why did he stop "to compose himself"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Following situation:

The protagonist of a story arrived at a gallery and observes the interior of it. Afterwards he *stopped to compose himself*.

I looked *to compose oneself* up in a dictionary, but I wonder what looking at the gallery has to do with composing oneself. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Was he trying to steal something from the gallery? Usually *compose oneself* means trying to calm yourself (from being nervous, angry, etc.).

Comment: The owner of the gallery was murdered and the protagonist probably wants to visit the gallery to get more information about him. Exactly that's why I am confused about the meaning. In my opinion there was no reason for him to be nervous.

Comment: It's not about being nervous or angry only, any feeling that could make him get emotional is qualified for the reason to make him need to compose himself (or calm himself down). I think D_Bester's answer is close enough.

Comment: I see...I think I understand it now, although I still wonder why the protagonist was so emotionally concerned  about the situation. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would conclude that the gallery was emotionally disturbing or sad. It probably almost brought the person to tears. But since he didn't want his tears to be seen by others, he stopped to compose himself. That means he stopped long enough to get his emotions under control so it wouldn't appear that he had been crying.

Comment: Maybe a little over the top, but in fact the owner of the gallery is dead. Although the protagonist was not related to the dead man in any way, it might be an emotional situation.